# Pycharm wsl terminal running in wrong directory

Tags: terminal, wsl-2

Im trying to run a wsl terminal on pycharm, everything works fine outside, but by default my pycharm terminal starts at docker-desktop-bind-mounts, which i don't want:

```
alvaro@DESKTOP-SG07AD5:/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-bind-mounts/Ubuntu-20.04/64513a8771337bf3b7e1cde3743afab3d9af2f58f73b5dceb629cec78091e538
```

This leads to some error using docker-compose, so I want it to start at:

```
alvaro@DESKTOP-SG07AD5:/mnt/c/Repositorios$
```

Or somewhere similar, i just dont want it to start at that docker thing.

This seems to happen when im running docker-desktop simoultaneously, doesn`t happen when i close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by closing all my WSL sessions, running `wsl --shutdown` in cmd, and then `wsl`.